# PySpark : How to Combine 2 DataFrame with same columns and generate a new DataFrame with unique and more recent rows

Tags: python, pyspark

I have 2 DataFrames and my requirement is to combine both and create a new DataFrame with unique and latest rows, For e.g.

DataFrame 1 :

```
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
|col A |col B  |col C    |col D|col E  |
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
|city  |prod 1 |9/29/2017|358  |193    |
|city  |prod 2 |8/25/2017|50   |201    |
|city  |prod 3 |9/9/2017 |236  |169    |
|city  |prod 4 |9/28/2017|358  |193    |
|city  |prod 5 |8/24/2017|50   |201    |
|city  |prod 6 |9/8/2017 |236  |169    |
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
```

DataFrame 2 :

```
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
|col A |col B  |col C    |col D|col E  |
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
|city  |prod 1 |9/29/2018|359  |197    |
|city  |prod 2 |8/25/2018|51   |209    |
|city  |prod 3 |9/9/2018 |237  |181    |
|city  |prod 7 |9/28/2017|358  |193    |
|city  |prod 8 |8/24/2017|50   |201    |
|city  |prod 9 |9/8/2017 |236  |169    |
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
```

I need to combine the 2 DataFrames from col A and col B and the resultant DataFrame should look like below.

Please note prod 1 , 2 and 3 is present in both DataFrame but is taken from DataFrame 2 as it has latest date (col C)

DataFrame 3 :

```
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
|col A |col B  |col C    |col D|col E  |
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
|city  |prod 1 |9/29/2018|359  |197    |
|city  |prod 2 |8/25/2018|51   |209    |
|city  |prod 3 |9/9/2018 |237  |181    |
|city  |prod 4 |9/28/2017|358  |193    |
|city  |prod 5 |8/24/2017|50   |201    |
|city  |prod 6 |9/8/2017 |236  |169    |
|city  |prod 7 |9/28/2017|358  |193    |
|city  |prod 8 |8/24/2017|50   |201    |
|city  |prod 9 |9/8/2017 |236  |169    |
+------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: One solution is to first `union` two dataframes, then using `window` function take the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your dataframes have only first four rows (for the sake of space!)

```
df_1.show()
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+
|col A| col B|    col C|col D|col E|
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+
| city|prod 1|9/29/2017|  358|  193|
| city|prod 2|8/25/2017|   50|  201|
| city|prod 3| 9/9/2017|  236|  169|
| city|prod 4|9/28/2017|  358|  193|
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+

df_2.show()
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+
|col A| col B|    col C|col D|col E|
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+
| city|prod 1|9/29/2018|  359|  197|
| city|prod 2|8/25/2018|   51|  209|
| city|prod 3| 9/9/2018|  237|  181|
| city|prod 4|9/28/2017|  358|  193|
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Then one way to achieve what you want is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
## change parameters in w, for partition and order
w = Window.partitionBy('col A', 'col B').orderBy('col C').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
## union just appends the dataframes
df = df_1.union(df_2)
## generate a feature which for latest row is True
df = df.withColumn('latest_record', F.col("col C")==F.last("col C").over(w))
## keep those rows in which the new column is True, and remove duplicates
df = df.filter(F.col('latest_record')).select('col A', 'col B', 'col C', 'col D', 'col E').distinct()
df.sort('col B').show()
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+
|col A| col B|    col C|col D|col E|
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+
| city|prod 1|9/29/2018|  359|  197|
| city|prod 2|8/25/2018|   51|  209|
| city|prod 3| 9/9/2018|  237|  181|
| city|prod 4|9/28/2017|  358|  193|
+-----+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Your approach is correct, but i think distinct is unnecessary and compute intensive here. y dont u use `first` for the window and then filter?

Comment: Could you explain more? I didn't understand how that can help.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine. I am also thinking of another way, to merge both DataFrames and then register a temp view and then write a SQL for the same purpose. I will compare the solutions for speed and cost. Thanks again!

Comment: @Prashy you could just persist your joined dataframe and use dataframe logic. i dont think there will be a speed/cost difference.